# Add dynamically to a lambda expression

Tags: java, lambda, javafx

Is there any way to add elements dynamically with say for example a for loop inside a lambda expression?

I have the current code:

```
FilteredList<List<String>> filteredItems = new FilteredList(data, e -> true);

filteredItems.predicateProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createObjectBinding(()
                    -> li -> li.get(0).contains(filterField.getText()) && li.get(1).contains(filterField2.getText()), filterField.textProperty(), filterField2.textProperty()
            )
);
```

and I would like to have the ability of adding

```
li.get(x).contains(filterFieldX)
```

to the lambda expression dependent on the size of li. So if the size of li is 3, then the lambda should have:

```
li.get(0).contains(filterField0.getText()) &&
li.get(1).contains(filterField1.getText()) &&
li.get(2).contains(filterField2.getText())
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you have your `filterField`s in a list, sure:

```
filteredItems.predicateProperty().bind(
            Bindings.createObjectBinding(()
                    -> li -> {
                        for (int i=0; i<li.size(); i++) {
                            if (! li.get(i).contains(filterFieldList.get(i).getText())) {
                                return false ;
                            }
                        }
                        return true ;
                    }, 
                    filterFieldList.stream().map(TextField::textProperty)
                         .toArray(StringProperty[]::new)));
```

Comment: You just made my day, @James_D ! Wish you a great day.